# Why is my ethernet connection between two Macs so slow?

Tags: file-transfer, ethernet, power-mac

I'm currently trying to port all my old stuff from an old Power Mac G4 (MDD) to a newer Power Mac G5 (Late 2005). Both have gigabit ethernet and so I decided to connect the two via ethernet cable (Cat6). Both are running OS X 10.5.8.

However... I'm only getting speeds of up to about 40Mbit/s, and it's taking hours (nearly a whole day in total) to transfer about 200GB. Are there any reasons why it might be so slow, and is there any way I can speed it up?

Thanks!

:-Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try FireWire Target Disk Mode. Boot the source computer while holding down the T key and connect to the destination computer. The source's drive(s) will show up on the desktop and you can copy files that way.

I don't know if it will be any faster; the bottleneck could be your hard drive speeds.

Comment: That would be great - and it would definitely be faster agreed - but the disk I'm trying to access is not the boot disk... Target mode only seems to mount the boot drive, unless you know of a way of accessing the other drives via Target Mode?

Comment: It seems to depend on the model. My MacBook Pro will share the DVD drive over FWTDM, but my iBook G4 doesn't.

Comment: Do they automatically show up if it's supported? If so then it's not supported on my Power Mac G4.

Comment: @Joe I believe they do automatically show up (in my MacBook Pro's case, a DVD had to be in the drive).

Answer (score 1):

I already have this problem in the past and solve it by disabling internet sharing. I don't know why disabling internet sharing speedup bandwidth but it maybe useful for you.

You can also try another ethernet cable.

Comment: I've tried multiple ethernet cables and they all produce about the same result. Also I don't have Internet Sharing switched on. :(

Comment: Try login to your session with shift key down (to prevent some automatic app launch), check odd launched app in activity monitor and kill them. Start again your file transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Considering they're older Macs, you're probably hitting the hard drives' I/O limit.

Comment: I wondered if that was the case, but I'm not entirely convinced... Running Xbench shows that the drives average at about 20MB/sec (going all the way up to about 80MB/sec) - I'm assuming that's also bytes and not bits. Duplicating a 50GB folder containing thousands of files locally takes about 25 minutes. But I guess it could have something to do with a network bus speed or something?